# Query params match in Istio Virtual Service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In a Istio virtual service, I have this working match block:

```
 - match:
   - uri:
       prefix: "/whatever"
```

It's working fine. But now, besides uri, I need to match also 2 query params as well. I tried this:

```
 - match:
   - uri:
       prefix: "/whatever"
     queryParams:
       app-id:
         exact: "whatever"
       token:
         exact: "thisisthetoken"
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't redirect to destination. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the request that fails?

Comment: Request `GET /whatever?app-id=whatever&token=thisisthetoken` does not redirect to destination

Comment: yep. that's the correct one. weird. are you putting the FQDN of the service? sometimes gives troubles if you put just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my virtualservice.yaml, I defined queryParams directly under "- match" section and it worked fine.

If I define queryParams  under uri and save the changes, it is automatically getting moved out of the  uri section and it doesn't work after that.

Probably it means that the queryParams are global for all uris and not for sepecific uri

Comment: http:
  - match:
    - queryParams:
        key:
          exact: "value1"
    route:
    - destination:
       . . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [HTTPMatchRequest](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest) part of Istio docs, table row describing `queryParams` says:

> **Note**: `prefix` matching is currently not supported.

So there you go. You can't match query parameters with `prefix` HTTP match.

Comment: I'm not matching query params with prefix match, but with `exact`

Comment: `match.uri.prefix` - this prefix matching, not `match.uri.queryParams.*.exact`

Comment: So, should it work if I use `match.uri.exact`?

Comment: Go ahead and try. Please reply if there are further problems.